# MongockException: Command failed with error 251 (NoSuchTransaction)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongock

I am using **Spring-Boot** `3.0.4` and I have upgraded **Mongock** from `4.3.8` to `5.2.2`.

*pom.xml snipped*

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongock-springboot</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v4-driver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have updated the old `@Changelog` and `@ChangeSet` annotations as explained in the doc https://docs.mongock.io/v5/migration/index.html, and similarly for the transactions https://docs.mongock.io/v5/features/transactions/index.html

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager;

@Configuration
public class DatabaseTransactionConfiguration {
    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory factory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(factory);
    }
}
```

---

```
package org.project.configuration.database.migration;

import io.mongock.api.annotations.*;
import org.project.domain.Questionnaire;
import org.project.service.QuestionnaireService;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

@ChangeUnit(id="questionnaire-initializer", order = "6", author = "dev", runAlways = true)
public class CU06_Questionnaire {
    @BeforeExecution
    public void beforeExecution(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        if (!mongoTemplate.collectionExists(Questionnaire.class)) {
            mongoTemplate.createCollection(Questionnaire.class);
        }
    }

    @RollbackBeforeExecution
    public void rollbackBeforeExecution(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    }

    @Execution
    public void execution(QuestionnaireService questionnaireService) {
        Questionnaire questionnaire = questionnaireService.loadQuestionnaireData();
        questionnaireService.save(questionnaire);
    }

    @RollbackExecution
    public void rollbackExecution(QuestionnaireService questionnaireService) {
        Questionnaire questionnaire = questionnaireService.loadQuestionnaireData();
        questionnaireService.delete(questionnaire);
    }
}
```

---

*application.yaml*

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: ${MONGODB_HOST:localhost}
      port: ${MONGODB_PORT:27017}
      database: ${MONGODB_DATABASE:project}
      auto-index-creation: true
  profiles:
    active: ${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE:dev}
mongock:
  migration-scan-package: org.project.configuration.database.migration
  transaction-enabled: true
```

however I'm having the following error when starting the application:

```
io.mongock.api.exception.MongockException: Error in 
method[CU06_OTQuestionnaire.execution] : Command failed with error 251 
(NoSuchTransaction): 'Transaction with { txnNumber: 30 } has been aborted.' on server 
localhost:27017. The full response is {"errorLabels": ["TransientTransactionError"], 
"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Transaction with { txnNumber: 30 } has been aborted.", "code": 
251, "codeName": "NoSuchTransaction", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": 
{"t": 1679076061, "i": 99}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}, "operationTime": 
{"$timestamp": {"t": 1679076061, "i": 99}}}
```

What am I missing that causes this exception between Mongock and the Transactios?

---

**Update**

As suggested I fixed the Mongock Runner dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongock-springboot-v3</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and I improved the `MongoTransactionManager` `@Bean` too:

```
@Bean
public MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    TransactionOptions transactionalOptions = TransactionOptions.builder()
            .readConcern(ReadConcern.MAJORITY)
            .readPreference(ReadPreference.primary())
            .writeConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY.withJournal(true))
            .build();
    return new MongoTransactionManager(mongoTemplate.getMongoDatabaseFactory(), transactionalOptions);
}
```

However, the exception remains, but only with the `Questionnaire` class and the corresponding `@ChangeUnit`. If I comment out the `@ChangeUnit` annotation on the `CU06_Questionnaire` migration class, all the other migrations work without any problem.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.project.domain.enumeration.QuestionnaireType;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@Builder
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Questionnaire {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    @Builder.Default
    private Class<String> idType = String.class;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private QuestionnaireType type;
    private List<String> questions;
}
```

---

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum QuestionnaireType {
    A(0), B(1);

    private final int value;
}
```

---

And this is the corresponding JSON that I'm loading:

```
{
  "id": Questionnaire-001",
  "name": "Questionnaire 001",
  "description": "Questionnaire to ...",
  "type": "A",
  "questions": [
    "Question-0000",
    "Question-0001",
    "Question-0002",
    "Question-0003",
    "Question-0004",
    "Question-0005",
    "Question-0006",
    "Question-0007",
    "Question-0008",
    "Question-0009",
    "Question-0010"
  ]
}
```

**Minimal Non-Working Example**

- https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/Mongock-Example/tree/NoSuchTransaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongock provides two specific modules to work with springboot (v3) and springdata (v4). You need to use the springboot v3 dependency as follow:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongock-springboot-v3</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This [sample project](https://github.com/mongock/mongock-examples/tree/master/mongodb/springboot3-springdata4-jdk17) is currently working with those dependencies.

---

UPDATE:

After review your [Minimal Non-Working Example](https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/Mongock-Example/tree/NoSuchTransaction), the error is due to Mongock is generating a proxy instance for your injected `QuestionnaireService` dependency and its return value `Questionnaire`. In this case, although proxing the `QuestionnaireService` injection is highly recommended(so the lock is guaranteed), the actual returned items(`Questionnaire`) don't need to and actually, in this case, it's producing the error.
So the suggested solution is to annotate your dependency `QuestionnaireService` as follow:

```
@Execution
public void execution(@NonLockGuarded(NonLockGuardedType.RETURN) QuestionnaireService questionnaireService, QuestionnaireRepository questionnaireRepository) {
    ...
}
```

Please refer to our official documentation about Mongock's proxy mechanism and how to handle it at the following link:

[Mongock Proxies](https://docs.mongock.io/v4/custom-injections/index.html#advanced%3A-proxy-explanation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the dependency and the TransactionManager @Bean,
however, the exception remains. It only happens with the Questionnaire class, even if it is very simple. I'll update the question with further details.

Comment: Could you provide the complete Mongock's output log?

Comment: I can’t view the content with the provided link, may it be private?

Comment: Sorry, it is waiting for moderation. Please try here https://justpaste.it/6qxwr

Comment: Ok now it works. Could you try it with the Mongock’s current version 5.2.4? I think it won’t solve the issue, but lets give a try.

Comment: Hi, I tried to update the Mongock version and also to downgrade from Java 19 to Java 17 but the error remains. I spent the last days to reduce the project to a Minimal Non-Working Example. Please find the project with a Docker-Compose for MongoDB 6.0.5 too, at https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/Mongock-Example/tree/NoSuchTransaction

Comment: Ok, we'll try to reproduce it and let you know.

Comment: I've just updated the answer with the fix.

Comment: It might help if Mongock users were made more aware that '@BeforeExecution' is where most of the in-memory work should be completed. I literally have nothing in '@Execution' and now treat the empty '@Execute' method like it is flush or persist command and put all in memory work in '@BeforeExecution'. I'm not sure that is a proper analogy to sql transactions, but it is working for me so far.

Comment: @tlarson, I am not sure what you mean by "in-memory work", but '@Execution' is where the actual change(potentially transactional) should be placed and the '@BeforeExecution' is where all the non-transactional work should be. For example, MongoDB doesn't allow having DDL operations within a transaction. So if you want to have an "atomic" change that creates a collection and insert some documents afterwards, you should create the collection in the '@BeforeExecution' method and the insertions in the '@Execution' method.